# Show map locations on uiimage

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, annotations, uiimage, mkmapview

Is it possible to somehow show the locations (annotations) from the map to a custom **world image**.
I have the coordinates in decimal value (42.0012,21.4167) and I want to show that location on a custom `UIImage`. I guess I would probably need to convert this coordinates (42.0012,21.4167) to a screen coordinates (x,y), but how big should the `UIImage` be?
I found a lot of material online but I got so confused that I dont know where to start from. Can anyone point me on the right track?

I've looked into `TileMap` and [route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) but I really need some guidance.

Comment: You'll need to read up on Projections. There are many ways to draw the surface of earth onto a 2D image, and the method that is used determines the method you'll need to convert your lat/long on to the image. Are you going to use MKMapView to draw the custom world image? In that case the question isn't about how to draw the annotations, but how to convert your world image into the same projection as MKMapView

Comment: No I'm not going to draw on MKMapView, It limits me on the animation that I want to add as a route line. I have already converted the degrees of the locations on to the ImageView and managed to make it look good. Thanks for you comment